# does anyone know the location of Oracle's 3 different berkeley db source code repositories?

Tags: source-code, open-source-definition, java

The Oracle corporation states that their 3 Berkeley DB family products Berkeley DB, Berkeley DB Java Edition and Berkeley DB XML are each offered under the OSS Affero General Public License. I have to imagine that suggests that the source code ought to be available in a source code repository somewhere. Or if not in a publicly visible repository at least available in full current distributions.

I have looked through all of the repositories at github.com/oracle and I don't see any of the Berkeley DB products being represented there.

I am especially interested in the Java Edition product. Oracle is offering a full distribution download of 7.5.11 and maven central is offering a more recent version 18.3.12 and that does include a source code jar, but the entire test suite, which does ship with 7.5.11, is not available for 18.3.12.

Also there have been breaking changes between the 7.5.11 release and the 18.3.12 release and I have been having a very hard time re-engineering the older test library to work with the latest code.

Would appreciate any assistance in locating a full distribution of the latest source code.

Comment: Could you perhaps link to that statement by Oracle?

Comment: What did oracle say when you asked?